# How to delete old executions and jobs from rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I am having more than 30000 jobs and executions in my rundeck. Is there any API or CLI so that we can schedule to clean periodically. Because of too many jobs and executions rundeck throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC Overhead Limit` and the services gets stops.

Also if there are more number. The UI takes long time to render the information.

Any documentations or scripts will be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Using RD CLI you have [this](https://gist.github.com/shamil/1f6524f06210252c7d13d0deb169bdc2) good option. So, if you're using Rundeck 3.1 or above, you can go to Project Settings > Edit Configuration > Execution History Clean (tab) and click on "Enable" checkbox (then you can define the parameters in the same page).

More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/project-settings.html#execution-history-clean).

Comment: That's probably the best argument to upgrade from 2.x to 3.x. Too bad we find the 2.x user interface to be more user-friendly and useful to our use case. No doubt the 3.x UI is better for somebody,

Comment: Using Rundeck 3.0.22-20190512, But Execution History Clean (tab) is missing.

Comment: Because that feature is available for 3.1.0 and above, I said "3.0", my mistake. Greetings!

Comment: Rundeck 3.1 had a [bug](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5274) affecting the effective deletion of past executions, use version 3.2 and above for the function to work

Answer (score 1):

If your looking to delete the log in Rundeck Server cli, You can find the log details in below location,

Log location : `/var/log/rundeck/`, `/var/lib/rundeck/logs/rundeck/\*/job/\*/logs`

Cmd to Clean the logs more the 90 days,

```
sudo find /var/lib/rundeck/logs/rundeck/\*/job/\*/logs -mtime +90 -delete
sudo find /var/log/rundeck/ -type f -mtime +90 -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

if your project is only one, you don't have to run the above script.

Go to Projects, Click on `recent` or `failed` or `running` tab and do a `bulk delete`